# Integration by Parts and Leibniz Rule for Differentiation under the Integral Sign

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration, derivatives

Basically a friend of mine and I have had this hot debate for a little too long, I contend that these two tools are not only logically unconnected but they require different assumptions (I believe one requires a continuously differentiable function and another requires it to simply be continuous). We've even gone through the proofs and disagree on how the assumptions are used. I don't see the connection...  Maybe I'm wrong, maybe they are equivalent (you have one as a tool if and only if you have the other). Anyway, any fresh perspective would be welcomed and any deeper discussion on either appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you, but it is recommended to see integration by parts as the counterpart of Leibniz rule for integration. This does not mean that they are "equivalent". But if you know one, you know the other.

Comment: Okay, could you elaborate on what you mean by "if you know one ...". by the way, do you disagree with my proposed solution? Btw, I DO appreciate them as sort of counterparts, the issue I have is I believe Leibniz's rule is more powerful in the sense that it works under weaker conditions.

Comment: Assume I only remember Leibniz rule. Then I write it down and I integrate it. I get the ipp formula. Finally, I make the ad hoc assumptions for the formula to hold.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay! So I think I have an answer to my own question and I would appreciate it if I had some confirmation on this.

Define $f(x)$ to be an continuously differentiable function, and $g(x)$ to be the Weierstrass function.
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n\cos(b^n\pi x) : 0 <a <1, b\in2\mathbb{Z}, ab>1+\frac{3}{2}\pi $$

Clearly integration by parts is not well defined because 
$$[f(x)g(x)]|^\beta_\alpha = \int_\alpha^\beta f' (x)g(x)dx+ \int_\alpha^\beta f(x){\color{red}{g'(x)}}dx $$
this statement does not make sense as $g$ is not differentiable anywhere.

On the other hand, we may come up with an interesting case where the Leibniz rule applies; namely, if we define the convolution as
$$(f\star g)(t) = \int_{\tau=0}^{\tau=t} g(\tau)f(t-\tau)d\tau$$
Then in particular we may show 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f\star g)(x)=g(0)f(x)+(f'\star g)(x)$$
using the Leibniz rule for differentiating under the integral sign.

Finally, in our case if we apply the convolution we see that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} (f\star g)(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n f(x) + (f'\star g)(x)$$

which is well defined because $f$ is continuously differentiable and the non-differentiability of $g$ is not a problem.

Comment: Regarding your Weierstrass example: the Leibniz rule does not make sense either. For a simple example where Leibniz rule holds but ipp does not, consider $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ and set $f(0)=0$. This is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, including $f'(0)=0$. But $\int_0^bf'(t)dt$ does not exist for any $b\neq 0$. So the FTC fails, in particular ipp with $g(x)=1$.

Comment: Thanks!  I really like this example!  But why doesn't my response work?  If it doesn't, then the answer should be edited but do we at least agree on the formula for the convolution's derivative (because the equation was something we had to prove in homework last month).

Comment: Your convolution formula has still nothing to do with Leibniz rule, as far as I can tell. I understand you really like all this nice material (convolution, Weierstrass function), but I'm afraid what you are doing with it does not shed any light on the question you raised.

Comment: Okay....  well I think you can prove that formula using the Leibniz rule, in fact I believe its fair to say that the formula is the "Leibniz rule for Convolutions".  But thanks again for the insightful example  :D